# Exclude specific rows using filter()

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have the following data example

```
test <- tibble(V1 = c("a", "b", "d", "f"), 
               V2 = c("a", "s", "d", "g"), 
               V3 = c("s", "e", "r", "u"))
```

I try using filter_all() to exclude rows in which the variables that matches with some value, like that are present:

```
test %>% filter_all(all_vars(. != c("s", "u")))
```

But it not works. it give me the following output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  V1    V2    V3   
  <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 b     s     e    
2 d     d     r
```

It's not exclude the row where the values are ("b", "s" and "e").

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be getting you what you're looking for:

```r
library(dplyr)

test <- tibble(
  V1 = c("a", "b", "d", "f"),
  V2 = c("a", "s", "d", "g"),
  V3 = c("s", "e", "r", "u")
)

test |> filter(if_all(.fns = ~ !(.x %in% c("s", "u"))))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 d     d     r
```

(Using `filter(if_all(...))` as the slightly updated `dplyr` method)

`%in%` is checking for the presence of 's' and 'u' across all columns for each row of the data frame.

Comment: If I wanna select specific cols, how can I do it?

Comment: Pass the column names to `select`

Answer (score 1):

`filter_all()` has been superseded, so you probably want to use functions that are replacing it in case newer functions build off of them. Per `?filter_all`:

> Scoped verbs (_if, _at, _all) have been superseded by the use of
> across() in an existing verb. See vignette("colwise") for details.

Using `across()` with `filter()` is awkward, but there are functions `if_all()` and `if_any()` that work in its place nicely for this specific purpose.

```r
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)

test <- tibble(
  V1 = c("a", "b", "d", "f"),
  V2 = c("a", "s", "d", "g"),
  V3 = c("s", "e", "r", "u")
)

# Filter out all rows where s or u appears anywhere
test %>%
  filter(if_all(everything(),
                function(x) {
                  !(x %in% c("s", "u"))
                }))
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   V1    V2    V3   
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>
#> 1 d     d     r
```

Answer (score 1):

- We can use `rowwise` from `dplyr` library

```
library(dplyr)

test |> 
    rowwise() |>
    filter(!any(c_across() %in% c("s", "u")))
```

- output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 3
# Rowwise: 
  V1    V2    V3   
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 d     d     r
```